# std::ofstream appending files

Tags: c++, fstream

So I want to input something in a file but it doesn't seem to work. My code is this:

```
  ofstream f("reservedTables.DAT");  
  cin >> table;
  f.open("reservedTables.DAT", ios::out | ios::app);
  f << table;
  f.close();
```

What am I doing wrong? I write the number for the variable `table` but it doesn't appear in the file that I put it in

Answer (score 5):

Quick walk through:

```
ofstream f("reservedTables.DAT");
```

Allocates stream and opens the file.

```
cin >> table;
```

Reads in input from user.

```
f.open("reservedTables.DAT", ios::out | ios::app);
```

Attempts to re-open the file. Will fail.

```
f << table;
```

Stream is in failed state after failed open  and cannot be written.

```
f.close();
```

closes file.

## Solution

Only open the file once and check for errors.

```
ofstream f("reservedTables.DAT", ios::app); // no need for ios::out. 
                                            // Implied by o in ofstream  
cin >> table;
if (f.is_open()) // make sure file opened before writing
{
    if (!f << table) // make sure file wrote
    {
        std::cerr << "Oh snap. Failed write".
    }
    f.close(); // may not be needed. f will automatically close when it 
               // goes out of scope
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "Oh snap. Failed open".
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Side note: `ios::out` is not necessary when creating a `std::ofstream`, as it is already an output stream and will add `ios::out` itself.

Comment: Ja. Removed the wrong `ios::out |` I should know better than to play fastest gun in the west.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are opening the file twice.

If you call `open`, you are actually calling `rdbuf()->open(filename, mode | ios_base::out)`. Note that ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)):

> If the associated file was already open, returns a null pointer right away.

Because a null pointer has been returned, it is assigned to the internal file buffer, and no file is opened anymore. This means that any attempts to write to it fail.

The constructor already opens the file if you specify a filename, so you don't need to call `open`:

```
std::ofstream f("reservedTables.DAT");  
std::cin >> table;
f << table;
f.close();
```

Comment: @rRakete1111 then how do I append it when I'm writing in it if I don't open it? Sorry I have used fstream that much, and the only methond of append that I know is when you open the file

Comment: @Roland If you look at the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream), you'd notice that it also accepts a defaulted mode as a second argument.